# how to get one by one value(id) from a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please tell me how to get one one value from a table and insert this value in another table.

```
Table1     Table2
Col1       Col1  Col2 
10         16    Null 
4          17    Null
8
9
```

I want to insert value in Table2 as shown below.

```
    Table2
    column 1   column 2
    10          16
    10          17
    4           16
    4           17
    8           16
    8           17
    9           16
    9           17
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: can u add table schema in your question or on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT t1.col1, 
       t2.col2 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) rno, 
               * 
        FROM   table1) t1 
       CROSS JOIN table2 t2 
ORDER  BY t1.rno  
Go
delete from table2 where col2 is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cross join`:

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b24e7/4)**

```
insert into table2
select t1.col1 , t2.col1 col2
from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2;


--if you don't need null values
delete table2 where col2 is null;

--results
select * from table2;
```